# MongoDB replicaSet pymongo connection

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I've got three mongod nodes, added to replicaSet(for example localhost:27001,27002,27003).
How to connect to it from pymongo if application doesn't know which node is Primary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only to supply each of the replicas and the driver will select the primary for you.  See documentation here:

[pymongo Conneting to Replica Set](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.10.1/examples/replica_set.html#id1)

Specifically

```
>>> Connection("mongodb://morton.local:27017,morton.local:27018,morton.local:27019")
Connection(['morton.local:27019', 'morton.local:27017', 'morton.local:27018'])
```